# navbar toggler not showing collapsed links

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

under my `container-fluid cont` I am writing my custom nav-bar using bootstrap.

The problem is that **when I click the toggler (humburger) nothing show up.** instead I want that when I view it in mobile size, it would collapse and when I click the toggler it should show the `ul` list of links. What can I change?

```
<!-- NAV BAR -->
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-custom navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" height="50px" width="auto"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCustom" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCustom">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active samecolor">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#home">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#orari">ORARI</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#luogo">DOVE SIAMO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about.hmtl">CHI SIAMO</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</nav>
```

these are some of the changes I made on the **css** side:

```
/*CHANGING SOME BOOTS TRAP NAV*/
.navbar-custom { 
    background-color: #F5D236; 
} 

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #223D94;
}

/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #223D94;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-item {
    color: #223D94;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add JS files

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/